# How to update the tabBar Image badge

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, core-data

How can i update the bag image with number of items in my core data

[image]

Comment: Could you just turn up the brightness of your screen, a little? It's a bit hard to see the code you've already tried...

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
tabBarItem.badgeValue = "<number_you_want>"
```

`tabBarItem` is your bag item.

Comment: Am not using tabBar

Comment: If you don't use a tabbar you have to add an uiview above your image in the top right corner, try this: https://github.com/marketplacer/swift-badge

Comment: Thank you i found this https://github.com/mustafaibrahim989/MIBadgeButton-Swift